# Entity Framework : The property X is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

Thanks in advance: I am checking for an object in database & if that object is available I want to update its non primary key values else I want to insert a new object into the database, but I am getting an error

> The property 'OPRQINBE' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Here is my code snippet

```
var be = beBindingSource.Current as BE;

var obj = _db.BEs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EIACODXA.Equals(be.EIACODXA) && 
                                      x.LSACONXB.Equals(be.LSACONXB) && 
                                      x.LCNTYPXB.Equals(be.LCNTYPXB) && 
                                      x.ALTLCNXB == _alc && 
                                      x.RAMINDBD.Equals(be.RAMINDBD) && 
                                      x.OPRQINBE.Equals(be.OPRQINBE));

if (obj != null)
{
    // update existing object
    _db.Entry(obj).CurrentValues.SetValues(be);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    Util.DisplayInformation("Data updated successfully.");
}
else
{
    // adding new object
    _db.BEs.Add(be);    // exception occurs here
    _db.SaveChanges();

    Util.DisplayInformation("Data added successfully.");
}
```

Code is working OK for updation.... also tried

```
            _db.BEs.Add(new BE()
            {
                EIACODXA = be.EIACODXA,
                LSACONXB = be.LSACONXB,
                ALTLCNXB = be.ALTLCNXB,
                LCNTYPXB = be.LCNTYPXB,
                RAMINDBD = be.RAMINDBD,
                OPRQINBE = be.OPRQINBE,
                ALDTXXBE = be.ALDTXXBE,
                OPAVAIBE = be.OPAVAIBE,
                STABYTBE = be.STABYTBE
            });
```

Definition of BE is as follows

```
public partial class BE
{
    // Primary Key is combination of all foreign keys and OPRQINBE

    public string EIACODXA { get; set; }       //foreign key
    public string LSACONXB { get; set; }       //foreign key
    public short ALTLCNXB { get; set; }        //foreign key
    public string LCNTYPXB { get; set; }       //foreign key
    public string RAMINDBD { get; set; }       //foreign key
    public string OPRQINBE { get; set; }       //key
    public Nullable<int> ALDTXXBE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> STABYTBE { get; set; }
    public decimal OPAVAIBE { get; set; }

    public virtual BD BD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are re-using `be`. You cannot do that - create a new one instead.

Comment: I tried to create new object as in updated question but no change in exception

Comment: Can you post the definition of BE so we can see what the key is made up of?

Comment: BE definition added

Comment: plz guide me in this regard